# Convert datetimePicker.Value to TimeSpan

Tags: c#

I am using Entity Framework (database 1st) and trying to assign a value from datetimePicker on a winform to a TimeSpan property to insert into a database:

```
Schedule schedule = new Schedule()
schedule.time = datetimePicker1.Value
```

I think I figured this out a long time ago, but am unable to resolve it at this moment.  How can I convert the datetimePicker1.Value to time (DateTime to TimeSpan) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Well what do you want the `TimeSpan` to *mean*? If I have a date/time of (say) 2015-06-19T17:00:30 what `TimeSpan` would you want? If you're just after a time of day, look at the `TimeOfDay` property...

Comment: TimeSpan indicates an interval, not an absolute date. You need a start time and an end time to make a TimeSpan.

Comment: @Jon Skeet In my case I am only after the time value of the datetime

Comment: Then `TimeOfDay` is your friend. It's always worth looking through the documentation of the type you've *got*...

Comment: @ Jon Skeet I knew it would be something to make me facepalm myself, as it worked exactly how I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only want time component then maybe something like.

```
DateTime dt = datetimePicker1.Value;
TimeSpan st = new Timespan(dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second);
```

Alternatively as pointed out by (Hussein Zawawi)

```
TimeSpan st = dt.TimeOfDay;
```

if you want full time stored then a convert on tick might be nicely usable. (unsure on the fallout/behaviour of it)

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(dt.Ticks);
```

Comment: Jon pretty much answered it for me in the comments section, but I will mark this as answered since you posted.  The "Alternatively" is what worked perfect for me

Answer (score 5):

Try the following snippet:

```
 schedule.time = datetimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay
```